# Ionic 3 Cordova android build not showing up in platform folder, permission error

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework, npm

So I have an app that I need to build for android, but on running

> ionic cordova prepare android

gives following error in the command prompt

> (node:2775) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CordovaError: Failed to
> fetch platform cordova-android@7.0.0 Probably this is either a
> connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect. Check your
> connection and platform name/version/URL. Error: npm: Command failed
> with exit code 254 Error output: npm WARN checkPermissions Missing
> write access to
> /home/{{MYNAME}}/dirname/project-name/node_modules/com-plugins-atcamera
> npm WARN @ngx-translate/http-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of
> @ngx-translate/core@>=10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install
> peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN @ngx-translate/http-loader@3.0.1
> requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed.
> You must install peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN
> @ngx-translate/http-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of
> @angular/common@>=6.0.0-rc.0 but none is installed. You must install
> peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a
> peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself. npm WARN ionic-gallery-modal@0.2.7 requires a
> peer of @angular/core@^4.1.3 but none is installed. You must install
> peer dependencies yourself. npm WARN ionic-gallery-modal@0.2.7
> requires a peer of ionic-angular@3.6.0 but none is installed. You must
> install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! path
> /home/{{MYNAME}}/gt-Hub/gt-hub-app-pwa/node_modules/com-plugins-gtcamera
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR! syscall access npm
> ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access
> '/home/{{MYNAME}}/gt-Hub/project-name/node_modules/com-plugins-atcamera'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent

followed by some similar, then some linting errors

I have ran following commands in before to fix another error regarding permission

> sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
>
> sudo chown -R username  ~/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json
>
> sudo chown -R mehulthanki /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova

And lastly to fix above commands

> sudo chmod -R 777 usr

I thin I messed up ownership of files and permissions while trying to fix another previous error, which might have been caused due to ionic and cordova being installed with sudo, and actually yo fix that I ran the last chmod command mentioned above, so I could uninstall everything: node, npm, ionic, and cordova and reinstall ionic and cordova without sudo, but now there are other errors..

Any idea how I could fix the permission and ownership issues ?

**EDIT**
On trying run

> sudo ionic cordova prepare android

It gives the error

> sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall Cordova, then get **NVM** (node version manager) to install both Node and Cordova properly without sudo. Dealing with NVM is annoying at first, but then everything works much better.

Afterwards create a **new cordova project** instead of attempting to fix your messed up one. Nothing will work on that app if you can't even install cordova-android, don't bother trying anything until cordova-android is installed properly, without a single error or warning.